# Force reload EntityManager

Tags: java, orm, weblogic, jpa-2.0, entitymanager

My problem are that my `entityManager` have my daabase in cache. This are a heavy problem because I´m doing a aplication  prepared for many users and  I cant show actual data.

```
public List<Tripulante> listxxx(String tip,
        String uni, String est, boolean val) {
    em.flush();
    Query q = em.createQuery("select");
    q.setParameter(dat1, uni);
    q.setParameter(dat2, est);
    q.setParameter(dat3, val);
    return q.getResultList();
}
```

I tried with em.clear to.

Im very lost with that I dont know I touch in persistence.xml or weblogic in jndi

Comment: Show us the full sql statement in createQuery. Are you sure your changes are in the database, maybe you don't commit them earlier?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solve with that:

In persistence.xml i put that:

```
<property name="eclipselink.query-results-cache" value="false"/>
```

And in query that I doesnt wanna read in cache put that:

```
public List<Tripulante> listxxx(String tip,
    String uni, String est, boolean val) {
Query q = em.createQuery("select");
q.setHint("javax.persistence.cache.storeMode", "REFRESH");
q.setParameter(dat1, uni);
q.setParameter(dat2, est);
q.setParameter(dat3, val);
return q.getResultList();
```

}